# RStudio Connect, Packrat, and custom packages in local repos

Tags: r, package, local, shiny-server, packrat

We have recently got RStudio Connect in my office. For our work, we have made custom packages, which we have updated amongst ourselves by opening the project and build+reloading.

I understand the only way I can get our custom packages to work within apps with RSConnect is to get up a local repo and set our `options(repos)` to include this.

Currently I have the following:

```
library(drat)

RepoAddress <- "C:/<RepoPath>" # High level path

drat::insertPackage(<sourcePackagePath>, repodir = RepoAddress)

# Add this new repo to Rs knowledge of repos.
options(repos = c(options("repos")$repos,LocalCurrent = paste0("file:",RepoAddress)))

# Install <PackageName> from the local repo :)
install.packages("<PackageName>")
```

Currently this works nicely and I can install my custom package from the local repo. This indicates to me that the local repo is set up correctly.

As an additional aside, I have changed the `DESCRIPTION` file to have an extra line saying `repository:LocalCurrent`.

However when I try to deploy a Shiny app or Rmd which references , I get the following error on my deploy:

```
Error in findLocalRepoForPkg(pkg, repos, fatal = fatal) : 
  No package '<PackageName> 'found in local repositories specified
```

I understand this is a problem with `packrat` being unable to find my local repos during the deploy process (I believe at a stage where it uses `packrat::snapshot()`).This is confusing since I would have thought `packrat` would use my `option("repos")` repos similar to `install.packages`. If I follow through the functions, I can see the particular point of failure is `packrat:::findLocalRepoForPkg("<PackageName", repos = packrat::get_opts("local.repos"))`, which fails even after I define `packrat::set_opts("local.repos" = c(CurrentRepo2 = paste0("file:",RepoAddress)))`

If I drill into `packrat:::findLocalRepoForPkg`, it fails because it can't find a file/folder called: "C://". I would have thought this is guaranteed to fail, because repos follow the C://bin/windows/contrib/3.3/ structure. At no point would a repo have the structure it's looking for?

I think this last part is showing I'm materially misunderstanding something. Any guidance on configuring my repo so `packrat` can understand it would be great.

Answer (score 5):

One should always check what options RStudio connect supports at the moment:
https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/r/package-management/#private-packages

Personally I dislike all options for including local/private packages, as it defeats the purpose of having a nice easy target for deploying shiny apps. In many cases, I can't just set up local repositories in the organization because, I do not have clearance for that. It is also inconvenient that I have to email IT-support to make them manually install new packages. Overall I think RS connect is great product because it is simple, but when it comes to local packages it is really not.

I found a nice alternative/Hack to Rstudio official recommendations. I suppose thise would also work with shinyapps.io, but I have not tried. The solution goes like:

1. add to global.R if(!require(local_package) ) devtools::load_all("./local_package")
2. Write a script that copies all your source files, such that you get a shinyapp with a source directory for a local package inside, you could call the directory for `./inst/shinyconnect/` or what ever and local package would be copied to `./inst/shinyconnect/local_package`
   manifest.
3. add script `./shinyconnect/packrat_sees_these_dependencies.R` to shiny folder, this will be picked up by packrat-manifest
4. Hack rsconnet/packrat to ignore specifically named packages when building

**(1)**

```
#start of global.R...
#load more packages for shiny
library(devtools) #need for load_all
library(shiny)
library(htmltools) #or what ever you need


#load already built local_package or for shiny connection pseudo-build on-the-fly and load
if(!require(local_package)) {
  #if local_package here, just build on 2 sec with devtools::load_all()
  if(file.exists("./DESCRIPTION")) load_all(".") #for local test on PC/Mac, where the shinyapp is inside the local_package
  if(file.exists("./local_package/DESCRIPTION")) load_all("./local_package/") #for shiny conenct where local_package is inside shinyapp
}
library(local_package) #now local_package must load
```

**(3)**
make script loading all the dependencies of your local package. Packrat will see this. The script will never be actually be executed. Place it at `./shinyconnect/packrat_sees_these_dependencies.R`

```
#these codelines will be recognized by packrat and package will be added to manifest
library(randomForest)
library(MASS)
library(whateverpackageyouneed)
```

**(4)** During deployment, manifest generator (packrat) will ignore the existence of any named local_package. This is an option in packrat, but rsconnect does not expose this option. A hack is to load rsconnect to memory and and modify the sub-sub-sub-function `performPackratSnapshot()` to allow this. In script below, I do that and deploy a shiny app.

```
library(rsconnect)


orig_fun = getFromNamespace("performPackratSnapshot", pos="package:rsconnect")

#packages you want include manually, and packrat to ignore
ignored_packages = c("local_package")

#highjack rsconnect
local({
  assignInNamespace("performPackratSnapshot",value =  function (bundleDir, verbose = FALSE) {
      owd <- getwd()
      on.exit(setwd(owd), add = TRUE)
      setwd(bundleDir)
      srp <- packrat::opts$snapshot.recommended.packages()
      packrat::opts$snapshot.recommended.packages(TRUE, persist = FALSE)
      packrat::opts$ignored.packages(get("ignored_packages",envir = .GlobalEnv)) #ignoreing packages mentioned here
      print("ignoring following packages")
      print(get("ignored_packages",envir = .GlobalEnv))
      on.exit(packrat::opts$snapshot.recommended.packages(srp,persist = FALSE), add = TRUE)
      packages <- c("BiocManager", "BiocInstaller")
      for (package in packages) {
        if (length(find.package(package, quiet = TRUE))) {
          requireNamespace(package, quietly = TRUE)
          break
        }
      }
      suppressMessages(packrat::.snapshotImpl(project = bundleDir,
                                              snapshot.sources = FALSE, fallback.ok = TRUE, verbose = FALSE,
                                              implicit.packrat.dependency = FALSE))
      TRUE
    },
    pos = "package:rsconnect"
  )},
envir = as.environment("package:rsconnect")
)


new_fun = getFromNamespace("performPackratSnapshot", pos="package:rsconnect")
rsconnect::deployApp(appDir="./inst/shinyconnect/",appName ="shinyapp_name",logLevel = "verbose",forceUpdate = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of nomenclature.

I have set up a repo in the CRAN sense. It works fine and is OK. When `packrat` references a `local repo`, it is referring to a local git-style repo.

This solves why findlocalrepoforpkg doesn't look like it will work - it is designed to work with a different kind of repo.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to also reach out to support@rstudio.com

I believe the local package code path is triggered in packrat because of the missing `Repository: value` line in the Description file of the package. You mentioned you added this line, could you try the case-sensitive version?

That said, RStudio Connect will not be able to install the package from the `RepoAddress` as you've specified it (hardcoded on the Windows share). We'd recommend hosting your repo over https from a server that both your Dev environment and RStudio Connect have access to. To make this type of repo setup much easier we just released [RStudio Package Manager](https://rstudio.com/products/package-manager) which you (and IT!) may find a compelling alternative to manually managing releases of your internal packages via drat.

Comment: Hi Sean! You've highlighted the two problems I had created for myself! The first was that I was referring to my C drive - I've now changed this to our network drive, using its server path. 
The second part was that I used `repository: value` instead of `Repository: value`. I've now got an error which implies I need to configure my RSConnect server to be able to see my network drive and I think it'll work.